# Arrays PHP Unidefined Offset Error

Tags: php, arrays, undefined

i'm getting an Undefined Offset Error when trying to create an array getting the data from another array. 
The array with the data is:

$dailyIncome

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(31) { 
        [1]=> int(0)    [2]=> int(0)    [3]=> int(0)    [4]=> int(0) 
        [5]=> int(0)    [6]=> int(0)    [7]=> int(0)    [8]=> int(0) 
        [9]=> int(0)    [10]=> int(0)   [11]=> int(0)   [12]=> int(0)
        [13]=> int(0)   [14]=> string(6) "400.00"       [15]=> int(0) 
        [16]=> int(0)   [17]=> int(0)   [18]=> string(5) "36.00" 
        [19]=> string(7) "5000.00"      [20]=> int(0)   [21]=> string(6) "123.00"
        [22]=> int(0)   [23]=> string(9) "101010.00"    [24]=> int(0) 
        [25]=> int(0)   [26]=> int(0)   [27]=> string(5) "23.50" 
        [28]=> string(9) "456464.00"    [29]=> int(0)   [30]=> int(0) 
        [31]=> int(0) 
    } 
}
```

This array represent the days of a month and payments done in each day.(No payments where done in most of the days listed in that array).
Now i want to do an array that sums the payments done each day in an increasing way. 
Example:

```
$increment[1] = $dailyIncome[1];
$increment[2] = $dailyIncome[2] + $increment[1];
$increment[3] = $dailyIncome[2] + $increment[2];
```

So have this:

```
  function dailyIncrement($dailyIncome){
    $increment = array();
    for ($i=1; $i <= 31 ; $i++) { 
        # code...
        if ($i == 1) {
            # code...
            $increment[$i] = $dailyIncome[$i];
        }else{
            $increment[$i] = $dailyIncome[$i] + $increment[$i-1];
        }
    }
    return $increment;
 }
```

But im getting Undefined Offset Error in lines:

```
$increment[$i] = $dailyIncome[$i];

$increment[$i] = $dailyIncome[$i] + $increment[$i-1];
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: As your $dailyIncome is a nested array: `if ($i == 1) {
            # code...
            $increment[$i] = $dailyIncome[0][$i];
        }else{
            $increment[$i] = $dailyIncome[0][$i] + $increment[$i-1];
        }`

Comment: I don't know how it became a nested array. How does that happens?

Comment: There must be something else somewhere that is doing it. That code looks like it should return a flat array. Are you sure that nowhere else the return value of `getDailyGraph()` is being manipulated, like `$dailyIncome = array(getDailyGraph());` or something?

Comment: yeah i found my error, i was calling getDailyGraph like this:                  $dailyIncome[] =     $user>getDailyGraph($row['membership_id'],$selectedMonthNumber);

Comment: That would do it. Now your `dailyIncrement()` code should work without modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is occurring because `$dailyIncome` is a nested array - `$dailyIncome` has only a single member (`$dailyIncome[0]`) but `$dailyIncome[0]` is an array with 31 members.

You need to either change the source of `$dailyIncome` to be a single level array with 31 members, or you need to change every reference to `$dailyIncome[$i]` to `$dailyIncome[0][$i]`

Comment: Im not sure when I defined $dailyIncome as a nested array, do you know how can I avoid this?

Comment: You would have to show us the code that generates `$dailyIncome` so we can see what is going on there.